# Error in callback for watcher "$route": "TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'closest')"

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, vue2

Disculpa las molestias pero espero que me puedas ayudar. Uso VueJS 2 Friends estoy programando en Vuejs y al redireccionar desde un router-link con la propiedad :to me sale el error en la pagina donde me redirecciona

`Error in callback for watcher "$route": "TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'closest')"`

`Cannot read properties of null (reading 'closest') at VueComponent.$route`

Mi código donde redirige es el siguiente.

````
   <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" class="feather feather-edit-3"><path d="M12 20h9"></path><path d="M16.5 3.5a2.121 2.121 0 0 1 3 3L7 19l-4 1 1-4L16.5 3.5z"></path></svg>
        Editar
</b-dropdown-item>```

Mi archivo del Router

{
        path: '/settings/roles-permissions/edit/:id',
        name: 'roles-permissions-edit',
        component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "role-permissions-edit" */ '../views/settings/roles-permissions/roles-permissions-edit.vue')
    },

Espero puedan ayudarme, Si necesitan más partes de mi código me avisan
Ayúdenme Porfavor
````